# This IS spam, right?

Tags: support

This answer is pure Spam and should be deleted, right?

- it's a response to an old question
- it doesn't really answer the question
- it tries to get the questioner to sign up for a training program

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6668/68

Answer (score 1):

Yes it was.  (I believe it has since been deleted.)